# Why are IV with odds ratios =1 included in the model?

Tags: regression, logistic, sas, odds-ratio

I am running a logistic regression where the outcome is sale success. I include different IVs, and variables such as talk time to the customer and the amount a customer is paying receive an odds ratio of 1. Which means both outcomes are equally likely. In how far do these 2 variables contribute to the model? What is the value added?

Comment: It depends on the model and the data.  One way to begin researching it and to help you develop a clearer concept of what you might mean by "value added" is to re-fit the model without those variables.  What changes and by how much?

Answer (score 0):

careful interpreting odds for continuous variables like those you describe, the estimate corresponds to a unit change in the variable, eg for 'amount a customer is paying' it may be one cent?

Comment: That is a good point. I was being sloppy with interpretation so far and when I saw the value 1.002 and tended to interpret it as if the sale success is equally likely. This is the odds ratio for how much the customer is already paying(monthly incurring cost), so it seems that the odds for an agent to make a sale are 1.002 higher for a customer who let's say has a incurring monthly fee of 19.95 compared to someone who pays 18.95. Would that be a right interpretation? If I would like to look at the incremental change of $10, can I just modify the odds ratio to 1.02?

Comment: you might want to carve up the variable into categories to help present/interpret the results (eg change the IV to <50, >50, or whatever). For an OR corresponding to an incremental change of 10 just redefine the variable as x/10. Or you could plot the odds ratio on the y axis and change in fee on the x-axis (ie the original, continuous variable) without a loss of info